# Java API Design - Internal Design

Tags: java, api

I'm making my first API that gets data and parses it from websites. So there is a lot of network and parsing in it. I read about API's having an internal packages in which shouldn't be public; like in Javadocs. So my question is what should and shouldn't be put in the internal package. Here is my package design, I'm leaving out the non important ones.

```
.networkstats
.networkstats.model
.networkstats.parser
```

Inside `networkstats` package there is a class called `NetworkStats`. That is the main class that handles and retrieves all of the network connections. It then uses the classes inside the `parser` package to process the data. After it returns a Model class that holds the data inside the `model` package. I want to include the internal package because there will be some classes and interfaces that aren't meant to be used by the users.

For example I want to make a class the handles all of the network connections so the other classes like `NetworkStats` can access it. Reason I want to do that is because I don't want to copy the code in other classes when It can be in one place. Of course I don't want other users using this class so I would put it in the internal package? I would also put my `parser` package in the internal one too. So my main question is that do you put classes and interfaces that aren't meant to be used in the public in the internal package? I know they *can* still access it.

```
.networkStats.internal.DataManager // class that handles network connections
.networkStats.internal.parser
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might find this Java API design checklist helpful. The first section is about package design.

http://theamiableapi.com/2012/01/16/java-api-design-checklist/

Ferenc

Comment: Thanks, That page really helped me out. I know understand it better plus that link has a lot more information that will help me.

Answer (score 3):

first of all I'd like to say sub packages are the same as any other package, there is no such thing as private packages in regular java, if you want that kind of feature you'll have to use OSGi

That said, if you want to protect classes from being accessed, just remove the public on the class name, and leave public only the "API" classes, this is, the classes that your users will access (calling users the developers that uses the framework).

The more packages you create, the more "private functionality" you'll have to expose.

Comment: I have heard about OSGI but not really sure what it is, Thanks, I now know that I should change the accessibly on the classes like you said.